# how do i drill down through a data model return the specific value for keys at the lowest level

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, model

i have data in a model defined in the following way

```
struct pickerDataModel:Decodable{
    var material: [[String: [String: [details]]]]?
}
struct details :Decodable{
    var min, wallmin, wallstd, max: String?
    var std, wallmax, mouldid: String?
}
```

i decode my json data into this model, and then im trying to drill down through the data
I'm retrieving specific values from this as follows

```
    let matr = (data as NSDictionary).object(forKey: selectorKeyLetters[component0Row])
    let matt = (matr as! NSDictionary).object(forKey: selectorKeyNumbers[component1Row])
```

if i print out "matt" to the console i get the following output :-

> Optional(<Swift.__SwiftDeferredNSArray 0x6000024793c0>(
> test.details(min: Optional("75"), wallmin: Optional("5"), wallstd:
> Optional("17"), max: Optional("500"), std: Optional("150"), wallmax:
> Optional("30"), mouldid: Optional("136")) ) )

how do i then get the values for min:, max: wallmin: etc, as the variable "matt" is of type Any, and so there are no key values.

I've tried every combination i can think of to get key values but nothing works, and searched for a solution with no success.
can someone advise what I'm doing wrong, as im lost.
am i using the data model correctly?
matr gets me a specific material, and matt gets me a specific size. i now want to get at the "details" from the model for that specific material and size.

hope this question is understandable.

i'm new to learning swift, and am converting an app from objC hence the confusion.

Comment: Your definition of `material` seems to be an array of dictionaries where the values of the dictionaries is a dictionary, is this correct?

Comment: material is an array of dictionaries as you say. the first key is the material type, which hold an array of dictionary sizes. the second key is the material size, which holds an array of dictionary details. The code for variable "matr" works and returns 67 key values. the code for variable matt returns the output I've shown in the console, and should be another dictionary with one key, and an array of dictionary values (min, max,wallmax etc). i then need to get these last keys and values into a usable format, but i can't access them.

Comment: If you have specific keys like this wouldn't it be better to decode the dictionaries into custom types? Also, dictionaries are unordered so you can't say the first key is this and the second that etc